# transience and recurrence of a random walk

Tags: probability, random-walk

I have a random walk $\{X_n\}$ where each transition causes moving one step to the right (with probability $p$) and one step to the left (with probability $1-p$). Now $X_n \to \infty$ as $n\to\infty$ given that $X_0=0$. I need to prove that the random walk is transient. I can understand it intuitively. But, I want to prove it formally by showing $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}p_{00}^{n} < \infty.$$

Another question: If $X_n \to 0$ as $n\to\infty $ given that $X_0=0$, does that imply that the random walk is recurrent. I don't think so. Am I wrong ?

Comment: Since the random walk either steps to the left or to the right, it is impossible that $X_n\to0$.

Comment: this is not correct. if $p=1/2$ then $X_n \to 0$ as $n\to\infty $.

Comment: No, you are wrong. If $p=1/2$ the random walk is recurrent and visits every state infinitely often.

Comment: Note that the state at time $n$ ($X_n$) can be written as $\sum_{i=1}^{n}Y_i$ where $Y_i$s are independent and $P(Y_i=1)=p=1-P(Y_i=-1)$. If $p=1/2$ then using strong law of large numbers $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}Y_i}{n} -> E[Y_i]=0$ as $n->\infty$. Hence $X_n -> 0$ as $n->\infty$. Where am I wrong ?

Comment: $X_n\neq X_n/n$

Comment: Well, prasenjit, I must admit having rarely seen so much arrogance, and so misplaced, displayed by a user on MSE. Please chill out.

Comment: Now, I have understood my mistake. Thanks for pointing this out. I am learning these things newly. Thanks again for explaining everything in the later part.

Answer (score 3):

$$p_{00}^{2n}={2n\choose n}p^n(1-p)^n= {1\over 4^n}{2n\choose n}\times [4p(1-p)]^n\leq  [4p(1-p)]^n.$$
The sum of the right hand side is a convergent geometric series if $p\neq 1/2$.

---

**Added:** I think I understand your problem better now. 
I hope this is what you want; let me know if anything is unclear.

You want to know how $X_n\to\infty$ implies $\sum_n p^n_{00}<\infty$.

To make a direct connection between the sum and the random walk, let 
$N=\sum_{n=0}^\infty 1_{(X_n=0)}$ denote the total number of visits to state $0$.
Then $\sum_n p^n_{00}=E(N)\leq\infty$.

Now define the return time to zero as $T:=\inf(n>0: X_n=0)$. 
By the strong Markov property, the random variable $N$ is geometric with probability of success $P(T=\infty)$.
If $P(T=\infty)=0$, then $P(N=\infty)=1$ which contradicts $X_n\to\infty$. 
Therefore, we have $P(T=\infty)>0$ and $E(N)={1\over P(T=\infty)}<\infty$, which shows that the random walk is transient.

Further calculations would  give the explicit formula $E(N)=1/(1-2p)$.

Comment: Thanks. But, I am not asking this. I am interested in the answer of my questions.

Comment: @prasenjit You said that you want to show $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}p_{00}^{n} < \infty.$ I have done this for you.

Comment: yes, i want to show this. But from  $X_n \to \infty$ as $n\to\infty$ given that $X_0=0$. Also, I want to know whether $X_n \to 0$ as $n\to\infty $ given that $X_0=0$,  imply that the random walk is recurrent. I am interested in the specific questions I have asked.

Comment: So you want to prove $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}p_{00}^{n} < \infty$ without using the formula for $p_{00}^{n}$? Your questions are not very clear, I'm afraid. Good luck!

Comment: yes. Till now i have proved that for $p > 1/2$, $X_n \to \infty$ as $n\to\infty$ and for $p < 1/2$, $X_n \to -\infty$ as $n\to\infty$. I want to prove that the random walk is transient from these two conditions.

Comment: @ Byron Schmuland : I don't understnad the statement "If $P(T=\infty)=0$, then $P(N=\infty)=1$ which contradicts $X_n\to\infty$." or in other words "why $X_n -> \infty$ as $n->\infty$ implies that the probability that it will ever hit state 0 starting from state 0 is always less than 1".

Comment: $X_n\to\infty$ implies $N<\infty$. Try to figure out why.

Comment: Suppose $X_n -> \infty$ implies $N=\infty$. Now, if a state is visited inifinite number of times what does that imply ? It does not imply that at $n->\infty$ it has a positive probability of getting visited. Confused .

Comment: If a state is visited infinitely often it implies that $X_n\not\to\infty$. Try to figure out why; this has nothing to do with probability. Look very very carefully at the precise definition of $X_n\to\infty$. If you are still confused, I suggest that you post a new question.